# Wildcards in default resource routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, wildcard

I have the following routes in my Rails application:

```
resources :photos
get "/photos/*id/stats" => "photos#stats"
get "/photos/*id/visitors" => "photos#visitors"
```

The id parameter is a wildcard that should allow special characters like slashes. Basically, "/photos/img/trial.jpg/stats" should route to stats method in photos_controller with photo id as "img/trial.jpg". 
This part is working correctly.

However, I am not sure how to use wildcard matching for id in the default routes created by "resources :tags", which are basic CRUD routes like "/photos/:id/edit" => "photos#edit".

Is there a cleaner way to use wildcard matching for default resource routes, rather than not use resource routes and specify those routes explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like

```
resources :photos
get "/photos/:slug/stats" => "photos#stats"
get "/photos/:slug/visitors" => "photos#visitors"
```

I am guessing that you are using something like friendy_id

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) and the answer above, you'd usually use the colon notation. The guide calls them *dynamic segments*.

These do however not work as intended in your case, since they don't allow dots by default (dots are reserved for specifying the format of the query). You override the default behavior by specifying your own constraint

```
get "/photos/:id/stats" => "photos#stats", id: /[^\/]+/
```

This for example only disallows `/` in the id. Slashes can not be allowed, since then we would have no way to detect the trailing `/stats`. You could possibly escape the slashes or replace them in URLs with something. The other answer mentions [the friendly id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), which could be a good way to automate this (I'm not using it, though).